# Array Collection, symfony: add a relation

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, arraycollection

I'm new of Symfony and php, and I'm trying to understand, without outcome, the array collection.

Now I have two entity, Mission and User, in relation ManytoMany. I have a form to create new Missions and a form to create new User.

Now I have to create a "modifyMissionAction" that allows me to set the Users for that missions, but I didn't understand how to do it. 
I read the documentation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) but it doesn't help. How could I do?

Thank you

This is my User Entity is:

```
 abstract class User extends BaseUser
 {

      /**
      * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission", inversedBy="users", orphanRemoval=true)
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_mission")
      */
     private $missions;    
     /**
      * Add missions
      *
      * @param \Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission $missions
      * @return User
      */
     public function addMission(\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission $missions)
     {
         $this->missions[] = $missions;

         return $this;
     }
//...
```

And my Mission Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Mission {
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;
        /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     * @var String
     */
    protected $name;
    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=600)
     * @var String
     */
    protected $description;
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="missions", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param \Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users
     * @return Mission
     */
    public function addUser(\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove users
     *
     * @param \Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users
     */
    public function removeUser(\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User $users)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($users);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all don't forget to add __constructor for both of classes and init ArrayCollection:

```
//src/WebHQ/NewBundle/Entity/Mission.php
//...
public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
//...
```

I assume that you want to add controller action witch allows you to relate user object or objects to mission object. Please read embbed forms part of [Symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/forms.html#embedded-forms)

Then create your Action. Most important is to add form element, with is embedded form of users entity:

```
// src/WebHQ/NewBundle/Controller/MissionController.php
//...
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $object = new \WebHQ\NewBundle\Entity\Mission();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($object)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            //...
            // Users objects embed form
            ->add('users', 'user')
            //...
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($object);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('web_hq_new_mission_index'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('WebHQNewBundle:Mission:new.html.twig', array(
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
        //...
    ));
}

public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $object = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('WebHQNewBundle:Mission')
            ->find($id);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($object)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            //...
            ->add('users', 'user')
            //...
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->add('delete', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $form->get('save')->isClicked() ? $em->persist($object) : $em->remove($object);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('web_hq_new_mission_index'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('WebHQNewBundle:Mission:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
        //...
    ));
}
//...
```

Check your routing. You should have route for edit action with `{id}` param. If name of param not fits you change it in route and in function definition:

```
// src/WebHQ/NewBundle/Resources/config/route.yml
//...
web_hq_new_mission_new:
    pattern: /mission/new
    defaults: { _controller: WebHQNewBundle:Mission:new }

web_hq_new_mission_edit:
    pattern: /mission/{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: WebHQNewBundle:Mission:edit }
//...
```

Then define Form Type for User objects:

```
// src/WebHQ/NewBundle/Form/Type/UserType.php
namespace WebHQ\NewBundle\Form\Type;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => 'WebHQNewBundle:User',
            'property' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choose',
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (Options $options) {
                return function(EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                };
            },
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

And register a type in service.yml:

```
# src/WebHQ/NewBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
#...
services:
    web_hq_new.form.type.user:
        class: WebHQ\NewBundle\Form\Type\UserType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user }
#...
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I still have some problem, when I call the page edit/mission the following alarm appears: Neither the property "user" nor one of the methods "getUser()", "isUser()", "hasUser()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\Mission". I edited the question and showed my whole Mission entity.

Comment: Im sorry, I have made a typo. In controller, editAction, change line `->add('user', 'user')` to `->add('users', 'user')`. "users" is an attribute name, "user" is a form type. This should fix for error.

Comment: In addition, you can change FormType parameters, when adding it to form in controllers action. E.g if you don't want to _require_ users to have related object, field not required, you can call it like this: `->add('users', 'user', array('require' => false))`

Comment: Great, it works. Actually it creates a new mission with the users associated; now I'm trying to create an editAction that allows to associate existing mission with existing user, but I'm reading the documentation and I think that I can do it. If I have problem I will comment here. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I have added both actions for you. The difference is that editAction has `$id` param passed from routing. Please check your routing file if there is `{id}` param passed. I have include an example of routing.

Comment: And another thing. This edit action has also delete button ;) So if you click save, `$em->persist($object)` will be executed and if you click delete `$em->remove($object)` will be launched. Full line looks like this: `$form->get('save')->isClicked() ? $em->persist($object) : $em->remove($object);`

Comment: Great again. I have done in a different way, but this one is better and I also learned something new. Really thank you!

Comment: Can I ask you one more [thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446285/arraycollection-retrive-collection-in-a-form?noredirect=1#comment32361973_21446285)? I opened a new post for it. (I will delete this comment because it is not directly related to the question)

Comment: @Jivan was first to answer :) And I think he is right.